# Como pasar correctamente un token baerer entre Angular y PHP?

Tags: php, angular

Hola estoy haciendo una app con JWT, y cree un Interceptor para poner en las cabeceras el `Authorization: Bearer {token}`, el api ya funciona pues lo uno que hace es que si en la header de la solicitud hay este Authorization imprima un mensaje de éxito o error, es para probar

Mi back-end esta así:

```
private function prueba(){
    $auth = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
    if(isset($auth)){
        echo json_encode(array(
            "msg" => "exito"
        ));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array(
            "msg" => "failed"
        ));
    }
}
```

El .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
CGIPassAuth On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</IfModule>
```

No sé si afecte la forma en la que llamo al servicio, la url es localhost/api/user/index, la acción inde de mi controllador user, dependiendo el tipo de solicitud(POST,GET) te abre una clase, en este caso, la de prueba si hay un GET

Y en el front el Interceptor lo tengo de esta forma:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

const token = this.getToken();

if(!token){
  return next.handle(request);
}

const headers = request.clone({
  headers: request.headers.set('Authorization',`Bearer ${token}`)
});

return next.handle(headers);
}
```

Pero a pesar de que en Postman si funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya en la app de Angular sale el siguiente error:

Undefined array key "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\api-prueba\controllers\userController.php** on line **104**
\n{"msg":"failed}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La línea 104 siendo `$auth = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];` por lo que yo entiendo que no se está mandando o recibiendo bien, pero hasta en la documentación oficial de angular viene de esta forma, cabe resaltar que en angular si estoy cargando el interceptor en el app.module